# Best solution for having the same height of elements and different number of columns in rows

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a problem with CSS. I have to do that the div have the same height of element no matter what elements are there (is link or not). You can see how it looks now on the picture. This section have two rows, one 3 elements, second 4. Link to CodePen: https://codepen.io/mkutaGD/pen/poVZreY

[image: How it looks like now]

Section

```
<div className="slider__items">
        {slider?.items?.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            className="slider-item"
            style={{
              width: `${
                isMobile ? 100 : 100 / (index > 2 ? 4 : slider.columns) - 1
              }% `,
            }}
          >
            <img
              src={item.image.url}
              alt={item?.image_alt_text}
              className="slider-item__image"
            />
            <div className="slider-item__info">
              <h4 className="slider-item__title">{item.title}</h4>
              <p className="slider-item__description">{item.description}</p>
              {item.show_url && <Link to={item.url}>{"Learn More >"}</Link>}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

```scss
.slider__items {
        @include flex-justify-align-wrap(space-between, none, wrap);
        width: auto;
}
.slider-item {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: max-content;
    &__image {
        width: 100%;
    }
    &__title {
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-block-end: 0px;
        margin-block-start: 0px;
    }
    &__info {
        padding: 30px;
        background: $ui-background;
        
        a {
            text-align: right;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: $brand-primary-colour;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 20px;
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could You please provide link to the repo ? :-) It will be faster..

Comment: I can't ;( It's only the project I do for company I work in...

Comment: @MarioG8 added link to CodePen

Comment: @Amaury Hanser has good solution ! In my opinion :-D Next time include codepen  immediately ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes you could make:

1. Remove `.slider-item { height: max-content; }`
2. Adds `.slider-item__info { flex-grow: 1; }`

`height: max-content;` won't allow your element to grow.
`flex-grow: 1;` will force it to grow.

```css
.slider__items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: auto;
}

.slider-item {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.slider-item__image {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-item__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
}

.slider-item__info {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.slider-item__info a {
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #007000;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider__items">
  <div class="slider-item" style="width: 32.3333%;"><img src="https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blta6d4a64bb45bf01b/blt2c5e117afa6173d4/62fce5faef61306ab603cfb4/poppy-g1bb548027_1920.jpg" class="slider-item__image">
    <div class="slider-item__info">
      <h4 class="slider-item__title">Education</h4>
      <p class="slider-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et</p><a href="/education">Learn More &gt;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item" style="width: 32.3333%;"><img src="https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blta6d4a64bb45bf01b/blt2c5e117afa6173d4/62fce5faef61306ab603cfb4/poppy-g1bb548027_1920.jpg" class="slider-item__image">
    <div class="slider-item__info">
      <h4 class="slider-item__title">Government</h4>
      <p class="slider-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item" style="width: 32.3333%;"><img src="https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blta6d4a64bb45bf01b/blt2c5e117afa6173d4/62fce5faef61306ab603cfb4/poppy-g1bb548027_1920.jpg" class="slider-item__image">
    <div class="slider-item__info">
      <h4 class="slider-item__title">IT</h4>
      <p class="slider-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item" style="width: 24%;"><img src="https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blta6d4a64bb45bf01b/blt2c5e117afa6173d4/62fce5faef61306ab603cfb4/poppy-g1bb548027_1920.jpg" class="slider-item__image">
    <div class="slider-item__info">
      <h4 class="slider-item__title">Healthcare</h4>
      <p class="slider-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item" style="width: 24%;"><img src="https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blta6d4a64bb45bf01b/blt2c5e117afa6173d4/62fce5faef61306ab603cfb4/poppy-g1bb548027_1920.jpg" class="slider-item__image">
    <div class="slider-item__info">
      <h4 class="slider-item__title">Corporate</h4>
      <p class="slider-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item" style="width: 24%;"><img src="https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blta6d4a64bb45bf01b/blt2c5e117afa6173d4/62fce5faef61306ab603cfb4/poppy-g1bb548027_1920.jpg" class="slider-item__image">
    <div class="slider-item__info">
      <h4 class="slider-item__title">Hospitality</h4>
      <p class="slider-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item" style="width: 24%;"><img src="https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blta6d4a64bb45bf01b/blt2c5e117afa6173d4/62fce5faef61306ab603cfb4/poppy-g1bb548027_1920.jpg" class="slider-item__image">
    <div class="slider-item__info">
      <h4 class="slider-item__title">Retail</h4>
      <p class="slider-item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```